# Program for this Alphabet pattern in c++

Tags: c, loops, nested-loops

Is there any other way to do this program with less number of loops.Its not much efficient

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int i,j,n,s;
    cout<<"Enter the value of n";
    cin>>n;
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
        for(s=1;s<=n-i;s++){
            cout<<" ";
        }
        char ch=97;
        int k=1;
        for(j=1;j<=(i*2-1);j++) {
            if (k%2!= 0){
                cout <<ch;
                ch++;
            } else {
                cout<<" ";
            }
            k++;
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
}
```

output:

```
Enter the value of n6
     a
    a b
   a b c
  a b c d
 a b c d e
a b c d e f
```

Comment: Less than what?  It looks like it should be possible to implement that using one loop nested inside another.

Comment: Less number of loops ? Why not just simply print them in that format :P

Comment: Your question is unclear but I guess this can be done with one loop with each line as a string.

Comment: Pls take some effort I can point you where you can find similar code http://cprogrammingcodes.blogspot.in/p/pyramid.html

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code-

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    int i,j,k,num;
    printf("Enter the number of letter \n");
    scanf("%d",&num);
    for(i=0;i<num;i++)
    {
            for(j=num-1;j>i;j--)
                    printf(" ");
            for(k=0;k<=i;k++)
                    printf("%c ",(97+k));
            printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Sample input and output-

```
sathish@ubuntu:~/c/basics$ ./a.out 
Enter the number of letter 
4
   a 
  a b 
 a b c 
a b c d
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    char *pat = "a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z";
    int i, n;
    printf("input n : ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for(i = 1;i<=n;++i)
        printf("%*s%.*s\n", n - i, "", (i << 1) - 1, pat);

    return 0;
}
```

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n;
    cout << "Enter the value of n : ";
    cin >> n;
    string spaces(n, ' ');
    string pat("a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z");
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
        cout << spaces.substr(i);
        cout << pat.substr(0, (i << 1) -1);
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```